# "merge" two arrays and iterate through the new array in Rails

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

Let's say I have

```
@colors = @product.colors.all
@storages = Storage.all
```

I need to loop through all combinations for these two and create an entry in a different model

How to tell the app to run this call for each color,storage and assign corresponding ids?

```
Stock.find_or_create_by_product_id(:product_id => @id, :color_id => XXX, :storage_id => XXX)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got a secret for you: Ruby has [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/). There are [lots](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) of [really](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-valid_encoding?) [awesome](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-tr) [methods](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) that are hidden from the bad developers that you can use to look awesome to your co-workers and they're all revealed to those in the know in the documentation. For example, [Array#product](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-product) is a really awesome method that will take another array as an argument and return an array with every combination of those two arrays (matter of fact, it'll take an unlimited number of arrays and return all combinations of all of the arrays). Pretty cool, right?

Here's how you might use it to make your situation easier:

```
@colors = @product.colors.all
@storages = Storage.all

@colors.product(@storages).each do |color, storage|
  Stock.find_or_create_by_product_id(:product_id => @id, :color_id => color.id, :storage_id => storage.id)
end
```

Welcome to the secret club. :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I jumped too fast through the array doc and missed that one. Thanks for pointing it out. Solved. For others, you may want to replace `create` by `find_or_create_by` method to avoid duplicates.